# Effective algorithm for this program

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to do the program which takes from user:
n - number of elements
m - the number of pairs (two elements are in pair)
then user will write all pairs > 1 and 2; 1 and 3, ...
And output should the number which have the most elements >> where every element is in pair with all others elements of that number.
for example:

---

INPUT: (first row n and m) next rows there are pairs

```
                                 5 6           
                                 1 2
                                 1 3
                                 1 4
                                 1 5
                                 3 2
                                 4 2
```

OUTPUT: `1 2 3` or `4 1 2`
(`1 2 3 4` is not good because the elements 3 and 4 aren't in pair)
(1 5 is also not good because 1 5 are in pair but they aren't the biggest)

---

I need to get this program working under 2 seconds with n = 100000 and m up to 300000
Is there some effective way to do it? I've tried to do it with all combinations and then I checked if all elements are in pair but it's not effective way (100 years to do it like that

Comment: Unless your user is a cyborg, there is no way he/her can enter 100,000*300,000 values in under 2 seconds... And please give us more input examples, what what is a pair? what does the `m` define?

Comment: Also, what please be more specific about the output, what do you mean `1 2 3` or `4 1 2`? The program should output both or randomaly one of them?

Comment: To restate: in a graph with `n` vertices and `m` edges, you want to find the largest [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) contained therein.

Comment: This is most probably NP-complete. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem.

Comment: More specifically: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs

Comment: It's Clique problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could keep an array of 10 elements (0-9), and then for each element keep another array of booleans of whether a pair was observed:

```
bool pairs[10][10];
```

When you see the pair (1,2), you could do:

```
pairs[1][2] = true;
```

To figure out which number has the most pairs, you can just sum up the boolean values.

However, you do have a problem that you want (1, 2) to be the same as (2, 1). To deal with that, you could impose an order:

```
void order(int &a, int &b) {
    if (b < a) swap(a, b);
}
```